# Time.parse not working in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a simple application just using Ruby. No Rails. My Time.parse isn't working.

When I type Time.parse("2017,10,1,3,00") or any other date and time it keeps returning the current date and time. Any ideas of why it keeps doing that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for parsing time.
It should be something like this

`Time.parse("2017-10-1 3:00")`

Which will output-

`2017-10-01 03:00:00 +0530`

Comment: @C.Yee - Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

For parsing dates as you are trying to do you can use DateTime.parse('string') instead of Time.parse which is used to parse time :).

You might want to require the date library first. by adding:

require 'date'

For more information check out:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html